# Error with miter limit in Graphics2D.draw

Tags: java, graphics2d

I have the below code:

```java
BufferedImage off_Image = new BufferedImage(2000, 8000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D graphics = off_Image.createGraphics();

graphics.setColor(Color.white);
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, off_Image.getWidth(), off_Image.getHeight());

graphics.setColor(Color.black);
graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(125, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10));
GeneralPath currentPath = new GeneralPath();

currentPath.moveTo(1788.32, 7450.98);
currentPath.lineTo(1767.5, 5898);
currentPath.lineTo(1767.5, 5897.84);
currentPath.curveTo(1758.14, 5894.52, 1751.96, 5893.82, 1748.82, 5893.91);
currentPath.lineTo(435.867, 5893.91);

graphics.draw(currentPath);
```

This causes a huge spike due to the mitering:[image]

Can someone tell me why this occurs? The angle between the start of the curve and its first control point shouldn't be sharp enough to be mitered like that.

I've also noticed that changing the lineTo before the curveTo to be:

```java
currentPath.lineTo(1767.5, 5899);
```

fixes the problem. This wouldn't change the miter length so I am also confused as to why this works.

Comment: I'm really not into this but if you look at the code Path2D they do some fancy space expansion - So if you are dealing with float coordinates that's what you are getting!!!

Answer (score 0):

this solve your problem.

```
graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(125, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 10));
```

JOIN_ROUND : Joins path segments by rounding off the corner at a radiusof half the line width.

JOIN_MITER : Joins path segments by extending their outside edges untilthey meet.

So, You have to use "JOIN ROUND"

[image]

Comment: Sorry for too Big image! I don't know how to make it small.